# Is there possible to use App.xaml code behind in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

In this project, A part of XAML is required in several places so I put it on App. Xaml it Ui part is working. but I need to add an item tapped event or anything. In order to have to go to another page, I need to use the item tapped command but in here they did not recognize its name in the app.Xaml code behind.

are there a better way to do this without put this on APP.xaml or if this is the way how to use that item tapped in here

```
    <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="PageTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="8*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0"></ContentPresenter>


                <customRenderes:NavigationImageButton Source="IconFAB" Grid.Row="1"

                                                      x:Name="Button1"

                                                      AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                                                      AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1.0,1.0,-1,-1"
                                                      HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                                      Margin="10"
                                                      Opacity="0.4"
                                                      ItemTapped="Button1_OnItemTapped"/>
         </Grid>

        </ControlTemplate>
         </ResourceDictionary>
         </Application.Resources>
```

I need to do some function when this floating menu is tapped how to do this are a there better way to do this without doing it on App.Xaml or If this is the way How to do this

Comment: Create a custom control for your menu and then implement it in the required page. You can create a bindable command and then implement the tap action from any page required.

Comment: So, is your issue that the customRenderer NavigationImageButton does not pick up the ItemTapped event?

Comment: @SparshaBhattarai   can you show me with this in example

Comment: yes it is one of my issuess and another one is this is a convenient way